# Get Current Location in background

Tags: android, gps, currentlocation

I am currently working on a project which is include in get current location every 5 second. I create a service for that. But current location not getting. I try [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882436/finding-current-location-when-the-application-is-running-in-background-is-not-wo) But I am not getting current Location.

```
public class Locfetching extends Service{

LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e("2", "2");
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    MyLocationListener myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, myLocationListener);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        Log.e("SERVICE123", "LATITUDE:- "+ location.getLatitude() + " Longitude:- " + location.getLongitude());
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("1", "1");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("3", "3");
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager = null;
    }
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("SERVICE", "LATITUDE:- "+ location.getLatitude() + " Longitude:- " + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}   }
```

How can I getting current location in background?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Location services for that phone? Is it enabled? If it seems enabled, please turn it off and on and click on agree (in the case of Android 4+ devices). Then check, it should work. Also check, whether you have added permissions for the same in the manifest.

Comment: I have also check Location Service enabled. @Eldhose M Babu

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made enough research [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a) is the best ans  i can provide you

Answer (score 0):

try checking if the location provider is enabled.

also, check if you're getting a location with the network provider

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, myLocationListener);

} else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, myLocationListener);

}
```